# Grails ORM - advantage of MongoDB over Mysql

Tags: orm, grails, mongodb

Not sure if this is a silly question but as an application developer that is abstracted from the database via an ORM (in my case I'm using Grails/GORM) what would be the advantages of using something like MongoDB vs something like MySQL ?

Does it really matter?... especially given that I'll be using the GORM API to access my data and will be identifying relationships between my objects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If all you're doing is storing data that's basically relational in a NoSQL store like MongoDB then you might as well use a proper relational database. The big benefit of the GORM wrappers for the NoSQL stores is that for data that is basically table/column-based you can use GORM, but you can easily access the native store to work directly with the document/graph/column/key-value/etc storage mechanism.

Comment: Thanks - I thought it was along those lines. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Anything having tree structure is better to store in mongodb, otherwise if data has table structure mysql will be better solution